# Rotate electron screen/browser window

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, electron

I have written an electron app which is being used on an All-in-One touchscreen computer.

I want to rotate the screen by 90 degrees to the right, so I want to rotate the electron app according to that.

So I am not able to work with rotating the operating system options (it's Ubuntu, command is xrandr --rotate right), because I can not re-calibrate the touchscreen.

How can I accomplish the roation in electron?

I think it must be possible, because there is a Google Chrome plugin out there which is able to rotate the browser window.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I am trying to do the same thing

Answer (score -2):

I think you do not need a formal rotation function. I would change the size of the window to the desired one, and then arrange the elements in the order that is necessary. This can be done with both CSS and JS.